# Android (java) - Adapter onClickListener method always return last item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I need to get the ID of the current item in my adapter but it only returns the id of the last added item. 
I can't figure out how to get around this.

```
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position, CardViewModel cardViewModel) {

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("id: ",cardViewModel.getId());
                    }
                });

            }
```

Click on the 1st, 2nd and 3rd item in order and output:

**3**
**3**
**3**

Must be:

**1**
**2**
**3**

My button isn't for my adapter view so I can't use: holder.button

Thanks...

**EDIT:**

[image: CardView]

When I click the button, I need to get the name on the cardView, but each time it returns the name on the last card.

Comment: This is because when the last view holder is bound, it's calling `button.setOnClickListener`, which replaces any existing listener for that button. This behavior is expected / valid. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to get the id of which item appears on the screen.

Comment: What are you overriding here? Where does `cardViewModel` get set?

Comment: I did not understand what you said.

Comment: Is this adapter for some list control or what?

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you examine it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting `cardViewModel.getId()` use position variable it will return current position of item click. 
You need to use ArrayList or List of CardViewModel cardViewModel as parameter then you will be able to get id of clicked item by

You need to pass List of `CarViewModel` as follows:

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position, ArrayList <CardViewModel> cardViewModelList)
```

You can retrieve the id of the current item clicked as follows:

```
CardViewModel cardviewModel = cardViewModelList.get(position)
```

This will give you expected result:

```
Log.d("id: ",cardViewModel.getId());
```